# OWL: property applied to only same classes

Tags: logic, owl, rdfs

I have some subclasses of animal, for example Dog, Cat etc.. 
I want the property isChildOf to apply only to class of the same type.
So for example I want that Dog is child of other 2 Dogs, but that Cat cannot be a child of 2 other animals that are not Cat.

That is the property:

```
    :isChildOf a owl:ObjectProperty ;
                      rdfs:domain :Animal;
                      rdfs:range  :Animal.
                      owl:cardinality  "2"ˆˆxsd:integer;
```

Any idea how can I do that?

Comment: You'd need an axiom for each class, I think. E.g., for the cat class: *Cat SubClassOf (isChildOf only Cat)*.

Comment: And by the way, you're not using owl: cardinality correctly.  If you're trying to say that everything has two parents, it'd be *Animal SubClassOf (isChildOf exactly 2)*.

Comment: That's correct, you do this, neither in OWL nor in SWRL. And as @JoshuaTaylor said, `owl:cardinality` is a part of an OWL class expression, thus, it can only be used in axioms using such a class expression and indeed only at the correct position. Note, OWL class expressions can consist of more than one RDF triple, see the [Mapping of OWL to an RDF graph](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-mapping-to-rdf/#Parsing_of_Expressions)